# JPA Criteria API checking if entity collection contains certain elements or one of them

Tags: jpa, collections, criteria-api, sql-in

I am wondering how to create predicate which will filter entities which collection property contains elements from collection given as parameter using JPA specification.
In this example I am building query for UserEntity to return users which belong to groups contained in parameter List.

```
List<String> groups = query.getGroups();
predicates.add(cb.isTrue(r.get("groups").in(groups)));
```

But if I understand it correctly it will return true if all or less groups are in this list.

I am looking for solution where a) all elements from list are in entity collection b) at least one (or like way)

Is there some easy way to achieve this? In fact I don't really need anything from GroupEntity so I don't think joining is necessary

Thanks for help

Comment: Hey ! I'm in the same situation, do you remember how you resolved this issue ?